# SQL nested aggregate functions MAX(COUNT(*))

Tags: sql, oracle, select, aggregate-functions

I'm trying to select max(count of rows). 
Here is my 2 variants of SELECT

```
SELECT MAX(COUNT_OF_ENROLEES_BY_SPEC) FROM
(SELECT D.SPECCODE, COUNT(D.ENROLEECODE) AS COUNT_OF_ENROLEES_BY_SPEC
 FROM DECLARER D
 GROUP BY D.SPECCODE
);

SELECT S.NAME, MAX(D.ENROLEECODE)
  FROM SPECIALIZATION S
    CROSS JOIN DECLARER D WHERE S.SPECCODE = D.SPECCODE
  GROUP BY S.NAME
  HAVING MAX(D.ENROLEECODE) = 
  ( SELECT MAX(COUNT_OF_ENROLEES_BY_SPEC) FROM
      ( SELECT D.SPECCODE, COUNT(D.ENROLEECODE) AS COUNT_OF_ENROLEES_BY_SPEC
        FROM DECLARER D
        GROUP BY D.SPECCODE
      )
  );
```

The first one is working OK, but I want to rewrite it using "HAVING" like in my second variant and add there one more column. But now 2nd variant don't output any data in results, just empty columns.
How can I fix it ? Thank YOU!)

Comment: You want the maximum code equal a maximum *number* of codes? That doesn't look reasonable.

Comment: I want to count number of rows(declarations) grouped by specialization code, than take the most popular specialization. Sorry for my English;( Is it clear now ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query based on description given in comments and some suggestions, so it may be wrong:

```
select                   -- 4. Join selected codes with specializations
  S.Name,
  selected_codes.spec_code,
  selected_codes.count_of_enrolees_by_spec   
from 
  specialization S,
  ( 
    select               -- 3. Filter records with maximum popularity only
      spec_code, 
      count_of_enrolees_by_spec
    from (
      select             -- 2. Count maximum popularity in separate column
        spec_code, 
        count_of_enrolees_by_spec,
        max(count_of_enrolees_by_spec) over (partition by null) max_count
      from (
        SELECT           -- 1. Get list of declarations and count popularity
          D.SPECCODE           AS SPEC_CODE, 
          COUNT(D.ENROLEECODE) AS COUNT_OF_ENROLEES_BY_SPEC
        FROM DECLARER D
        GROUP BY D.SPECCODE
      )
    )
    where count_of_enrolees_by_spec = max_count
  )
    selected_codes
where 
  S.SPECCODE = selected_codes.spec_code
```

Also query not tested and some syntax errors are possible.

Comment: Thank you, it works witout mistakes! Can you, please, explain a little bit this part - "over (partition by null)"?

Comment: To use [analytic functions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) you need to specify partitions in [`PARTITION BY`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF51197) clause to select group of rows like in `GROUP BY`. If you need only one group with all rows of dataset, it's useful to specify some constant expression. E.g. `1`, `'X'` and so on. `Null` also works. Personally, I prefer `null` for more code readability because it don't raise a questions like "Why choosed 1 and not 0?" and so on.

Comment: Thank You ! Great explanation. Can we use in this select GROUP BY expression instead of OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) to get same result ? I read about these expressions but I don't understand why I got error if I use max(count_of_enrolees_by_spec) and then trying to GROUP BY spec_code and count_of_enrolees_by_spec.

Comment: `GROUP BY` over full dataset (like `GROUP BY 'x'`) is equivalent to just `select max(COUNT_OF_ENROLEES_BY_SPEC)` without any grouping. Each group must be identified uniquely and divides source record set to distinct groups without intersections. Therefore with one group you can't distinguish between different `SPECCODE`s and just got single value of maximum record count without ability to link it back to `DECLARER` or `SPECIALIZATION` tables.

Comment: From other side if you do `GROUP BY` over first (1.) query with some partitioning then you don't give maximum value.

Comment: Regarding the error: if you have `select max(count_of_enrolees_by_spec) AS MAXVAL from ...` in your query without any other fields and after that try to select from this results with grouping by fields other than `MAXVAL` you got error because there are no such fields in selected set of data. Think about this like about sequential selecting of parts of objects. E.g. on 1st stage you select a count of wheels of red cars. On the 2nd step you can select only from counts and can't refer to car's engine, it's color and so on.